# Snowflake - Querying External Table from Tableau

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-desktop, external-tables

I am trying to use the Snowflake connector in Tableau to query an external Snowflake table.

I cannot see the external table in the list of all tables on the left pane in Tableau (only regular Snowflake tables), so I have tried to pull from the external table using SQL.

Running this from the Snowflake site gets me the contents of the external table:

select * from EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME;

Running the same from the "New Custom SQL" dialog in Tableau's Snowflake connector gets me this:

SQL compilation error: Object 'EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME' does not exist or not authorized.

I also tried the following:

select  from @DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.STAGE_NAME.EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME

...which gets me: SQL compilation error: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.

Any thoughts on what I can do to get this to work? I don't think it is a permissioning issue because I am using the same account to auth in Tableau as I am on the Snowflake website.

I'm guessing that I simply need to do a better job pointing to the location where the external table is, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does the query work from the console using the same USER/ROLE that Tableau is connecting with? Aka does the Tableau user have the correct permission?

Comment: Affirmative, it does work. I think it may be a deeper permissioning issue that's causing my problem however, because I just got this to work successfully using a totally different Snowflake ROLE and DATABASE. I'm pretty sure I'm going to be able to work this out with our Snowflake admin tomorrow, so closing this question.

Comment: `I just got this to work successfully using a totally different Snowflake ROLE and DATABASE` that seems the opposite of my "does it work with the SAME ROLE/USER", so I was confused by the affirmative, but the end point is the same. "Is your permission model the problem"

Comment: You asked if the query worked from the console using the same USER/ROLE that Tableau is connecting with, to which I responded "Affirmative, it does work." The "I just got this to work" bit refers to the first line in my post, "I am trying to use the Snowflake connector in Tableau to query an external Snowflake table."

Comment: I didn't see the change of topic from responding to my question, to the going back to your original first point. Anyways I hope you get this all working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a deeper permissioning issue that I will have to resolve with our Snowflake admin. I was able to pull to Tableau from an external Snowflake table successfully using a different ROLE and DATABASE, so marking this resolved.